# Place the encoded Javascript in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, base64

This is a HTML page which contains a script. This script in the HTML page is plain text. I want to know how to place this script with base64 encoding in html page. HTML file :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript</h1>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var pi = 3.14;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pi;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Script is :-

```
<script>
var pi = 3.14;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pi;
</script>
```

Base64 encoding of script :-

```
PHNjcmlwdD4NCnZhciBwaSA9IDMuMTQ7DQpkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgiZGVtbyIpLmlubmVySFRNTCA9IHBpOw0KPC9zY3JpcHQ+
```

Comment: Whatever do you want to do that for?

Comment: `atob()` will change the Bse64 string into the script string. But you'll probably need eval somewhere in there to get it working and into the DOM, so I'd advice against it. As Quentin says, what are you trying to do? Maybe there's a better solution than base64 if we understand which problem this has to solve.

Comment: you CAN'T prevent users from seeing/stealing your code..... !

Comment: I know atob() will decode that. But it is okay, I want to try encoding.

Comment: I want to learn how to include this encoded string into html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this will

1. increase the size of your script, since base64 inflates data size
2. provide virtually zero security benefit whatsoever (or any obvious benefit, for that matter), since users can easily decode the script just as easily as you encoded it

In case you are interested in making your script less-efficiently encoded for no obvious benefit, you can do so by base64-encoding the script (*not* including the `<script>` tags) and include it as a `data:` URL:

```
<script src="data:text/javascript;base64,dmFyIHBpID0gMy4xNDtkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgiZGVtbyIpLmlubmVySFRNTCA9IHBpOw=="></script>
```

This doesn't really provide any obfuscation benefit, as pasting the `data:text/javascript;base64,dmFyIHBp...` URL into your address bar shows the decoded text.

Alternatively, you could pass it into `atob` to decode it and then pass it into `eval`:

```
<script>
eval(atob("dmFyIHBpID0gMy4xNDtkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgiZGVtbyIpLmlubmVySFRNTCA9IHBpOw=="));
</script>
```

Again, this affords no security benefit, since any user can easily run this code with the `eval` and see the decoded text.